# How to make it run through the 3 validations before being able to send the form action to an address

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

My code currently validates that the name/email and postcode is valid before being able to send when there is NO address that the information is meant to go to in the form action ="". But when I put the address it's meant to go to it completely skips the validation and just sends whatever, empty or not empty.

Trying to re-position the form action, but really have no idea.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Food Delivery Form</title>
<h1>Online Food Delivery Form</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"   
method="get"  onsubmit="return validation();">
Name* : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<br />
<br />
Email* :    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<br />
<br />
Postcode* : <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" size="10">

<input type="reset" value="Reset"></button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="eresult" style="color:red;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validation(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
if(name=='' || postcode=='' || email==''){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name, Email and Postcode 
are required.";
return false;
}
else if(name.length<3){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name must be more than 3 
characters.";
return false;
}
else if(postcode.length<4){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Postcode must be atleast 
4 characters.";
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected results is for the code to validate that the email/name and postcode is correct before sending the information to the designated site. But it's doing complete opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your validation, your error messages are multi-line strings

```
if(name=='' || postcode=='' || email==''){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name, Email and Postcode 
are required.";
return false;
}
else if(name.length<3){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name must be more than 3 
characters.";
return false;
}
else if(postcode.length<4){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Postcode must be atleast 
4 characters.";
return false;
}
```

If you open up the developer console (usually F12), you'll see an error caused by an Invalid or Unexpected Token. Change these error messages to fit on one line to fix this error:

```
if(name=='' || postcode=='' || email==''){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name, Email and Postcode are required.";
return false;
}
else if(name.length<3){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name must be more than 3 characters.";
return false;
}
else if(postcode.length<4){
document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Postcode must be atleast 4 characters.";
return false;
}
```

Also, you have a closing `</button>` tag but no opening one! Remove that tag from the line `<input type="reset" value="Reset"></button>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, sorry that multi line string must've came about when I copied the code over into my question. That's not there normally, so to clarify if I turn it from multiple error lines into a single one, it will check for validation before sending the information to a website? sorry, feeling way over my head with this issue.

Comment: No problem, glad you managed to sort it! To answer your earlier question, JavaScript doesn't support strings that span over multiple lines - they will cause a syntax error, which will stop your code from executing